# How does variable assignment with BooleanExpressions work in UIMA Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I was playing around with variable assignments in Ruta when I stumbled across this script with a result I don't really understand:

```
DECLARE testType (Annotation ann, BOOLEAN bool1, BOOLEAN bool2);
ANNOTATION a1, a2;
BOOLEAN b1,b2;

d:Document{-> a1=d};

Document{-> b1 = a1==a2};
Document{-> b2 = a1!=a2};

"demo"{->CREATE(testType, "bool1"=b1, "bool2"=b2, "ann"=a2)};
```

I used the Ruta Workbench 2.8.0 with Eclipse 2019-09 to interpret a simple text file which includes the word "demo". Since I couldn't find any specifics on the VariableAssignmentExpresssion in the [Ruta Guide](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.syntax) and no exception was throw I expect this to be valid Ruta code. The output is shown in this [screenshot of the Annotation Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI9gr.png). As you can see, both boolean features are false and the "ann" feature is not present at all. What I've expected instead is

- *bool2* to be true,
- *ann* to be null (and listed as such).

Can someone point me to what I'm missing here? Or is this a bug?

Comment: You didn't miss anything. This appears to be a bug indeed. I have created a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-6191). Check it out to track the progress or even contribute.